# iOS Simulator - offline mode

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Does anybody know how to make the iPhone/iPad simulator become offline?

Regards!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) and temporarily block all connections from iOS Simulator when the dialog comes up.

Comment: Didn't get prompt. Added iOS Simulator to rules list manually and blocked all connection - no change. This doesn't put the simulator in "offline mode" at least not anymore. The simulator still reports an active network connection - just no connections work. If you're trying to test the reachability APIs, you won't get any satisfaction out of this.

Comment: @Steve the simulator has to make an http request before the prompt shows up. I've been using this method for years.

Comment: @Peter; when the simulator makes a request to web services it appears to be coming from Xcode in little snitch. When I use the simulator's browser, it appears to be coming from "MobileSafari" in little snitch. Blocking all for both of those as well as dragging the iOS simulator into little snitch manually and blocking all still wasn't enough to achieve the behavior you describe. Are you sure, with your setup, the reachability Apis are reporting the device as not having wifi and/or 3G, or are you simply using it to test connection failures?

Comment: Love Little Snitch, unfortunately the free license is for 3 hours only.

Comment: That's not a solution, it's a workaround. Ramis' answer is the actual solution (and free) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64098784/1456838

Answer (score 6):

If you set os x offline, the iPad simulator will be offline. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Ok, I have seen this answer in another question. It's obvious that the simulator will be offline if the computer is offline. I want a way to keep just the simulator offline while I continue connected to the internet

Comment: could you try creating another network device with TunTap (http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/), and taking that offline? @Claudio

Comment: Doesn't work for testing reachability...e.g. simulating a user who is in airplane mode or otherwise doesn't have internet access. The simulator will still "think" it has internet access and your reachability tests will return positive. Not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Install **Network Link Conditioner** from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?q=Additional%20Tools). And you will have possibility to change to offline mode.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool called "Network Link Conditioner" but it seems that its only for OX Lion and xCode 4.1+ installed. Take look at: http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/10/simulate-internet-connectivity-bandwidth-speeds-network-link-conditioner/ - i use it almost everyday :)

Comment: Hint: to get this tool to completely take you offline, you have to set the packet loss to 100% (up and down).  Putting max bandwidth to 0 doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test something in the local environment like a web app for iOS with cached features, you can add a rule to your hosts file pointing to your localhost, then you can comment the line every time you desire to make it inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, all app's network communication goes through one point. By commenting out a relevant code or creating a dummy error it's rather straightforward to make it look like all the responses have timed out.

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
//          if (error) {
              if (self.delegate) {
                  [self.delegate networkError: error];
              }
//          } else {
```

I find it good enough for the actual development. It's quick and cheap, even if a bit dirty, while allowing to continue working without the hassle of a constant WiFi toggling. Once successfully enabled, even pretty specific scenarios are easy to simulate.

**When the work is finished, turning off macOS WiFi for the final testing is a good idea, though.**

Answer (score 0):

iOS Simulators Offline Mode:

In terminal: sudo nano /etc/hosts
Add: 127.0.0.1 your-domain.com

more info  step by step : [medium guide](https://medium.com/p/37070407667c)

Answer (score -1):

On macos, turning off wifi and plugging your phone with USB hotspot mode on works a treat.
Simple and reliable for everything including testing reachability.